# PHP WebSockets getting request headers

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php) repository for my WebSocket server, the only issue as far as I can see is that it generated the socket IDs with

```
$i = 1;
while (isset($this->wsRead[$i])) $i++;
return $i;
```

What I would like is to pass an ID to the socket when I connect

```
ws://127.0.0.1:9300?id=12345
```

the problem is that I don't know how to get that GET parameter before the ID is assigned. I have been searching for a long time and getting nowhere. As far as I can see that only these functions can get the headers: **socket_read** and **socket_recv**, but the problem is that they somehow *block* the handshake, because if I use them, then in the browser I can see

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

Are there any other ways of getting the ID I'm passing while connecting?

Comment: In the `wsProcessClientHandshake` method of the library you might find it in `$request ` variable. But I'm not sure

Comment: You're right, I can get it there, but that's too late as an ID has already been assigned at that point. I need to get the headers at wsAddClient() function as that's the place where an ID is given to the socket.

Comment: Why do you even need the ID? Can't you supply your id with a message after the connection has been established and then map it in your code without touching the library?

Comment: I could and I'm doing it right now but this means that I have to supply an id to all the messages to check if the user is even allowed to perform any action within the WS.

Comment: my suggestion was to send the ID to the first message and then store a your supplied ID in an array using the socket id as the key. Then for any action you can lookup the supplied ID for the current connection